# Angular 2 render template after the PROMISE with data is loaded

Tags: angular

I'm new to AngularJS 2.0, basically I'm loading data through Promise in constructor, but the template is rendered before the promise is resolved.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Thanks,
M.

Comment: You should provide code enough to see what could be wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait for Angular 2 to load/resolve model before rendering view/template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731869/wait-for-angular-2-to-load-resolve-model-before-rendering-view-template)

Answer (score 4):

You can test the `data` before using it.

```
<ul *ngIf="data">
  <li *ngFor="let item of data">{{item.value}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: A good practice is to initialize a variable with `false` value that says if the content is loaded or not. Something like `isDataLoaded`. Then, after content loads, set it to `true`