# Wait for async data to load before rendering component view

Tags: asynchronous, angular

I'm struggling with the `async` pipe, I need to wait for the async data to finish loading before trying to render the view of the component.

I tried looking at this question where the elvis operator is mentioned:

[Wait for Angular 2 to load/resolve model before rendering view/template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731869/wait-for-angular-2-to-load-resolve-model-before-rendering-view-template)

I tried it like `{{model?['name']}}` but it doesn't seem to do anything because angular stills throws an error complaining about not being able to read `name` of `undefined`.

I initialize the `model` on `ngOnInit` but the data hasn't finished loading at this point (I think):

```
ngOnInit() {

  // If no model is set and the select shouldn't be allowed empty, set the model to the first option
  if (!this.model && !this.allowEmpty) {
    this.model = this.options[0];
  }
  // If it should be allowed empty, set it to null which will add an empty class in the markup
  else if (this.allowEmpty) {
    this.model = null;
  }

  this.onModelChange.emit(this.model);
}
```

Then it tries to render this bit prematurely:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>{{model?['name']}}</div>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let option of options | async">{{option['name']}}</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So what would be the correct way of achieving this? Can I set something in the component class to allow async data to finish loading before rendering the view?

Comment: It seems the `option` that is rendered doesn't have a `name` property. Try `{{option | json}}` instead, to see what `option` actually contains.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `?` with `[]`

If you use

```
*ngFor="let option of options | async">
```

then `option` in

```
{{option.name}}
```

always has a value because no `<li ...` is rendered when `options` hasn't yet emitted data.

```
{{option?.name}}
```

would be a valid use and do what you seemed to intend to do but as mentioned above, it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I just added it to be sure. But the main issue is with `model`, so this doesn't really answer my question :(

Comment: I see. I guess there is more information necessary about how and where model gets it's value from .

Comment: Model either comes from outside via an input or if it's not defined then it will be set to the first option of `options`. But since that is not defined, it just becomes `undefined`.

Comment: Does this mean that there's no better thing to do than good old `this.model = ... || {}` in such case?

Comment: What about `{{model?.name}}`?

Comment: @estus Setting a default value does nothing since the template seems to render before any of the functions inside of my component class. Maybe there's a hook to set a value before the template loads?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer That solution doesn't work either oddly enough.

Comment: Sounds weird. I think this would need a Plunker to reproduce.