# How to make Angular2 wait for a promise before rendering component

Tags: angular, resolver

First: Yes, I have Googled this beforehand, and the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731869/wait-for-angular-2-to-load-resolve-model-before-rendering-view-template) that came up isn't working for me.

**The Context**

I have an Angular 2 component that calls a service, and needs to perform some data manipulation once it receives the response:

```
ngOnInit () {
  myService.getData()
    .then((data) => {
      this.myData = /* manipulate data */ ;
    })
    .catch(console.error);
}
```

In its template, that data is passed to a child component:

```
<child-component [myData]="myData"></child-component>
```

This is causing an error that the child is getting `myData` as undefined. The Google result posted above talks about using `Resolver` but that isn't working for me.

When I create a new resolver:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { MyService } from './my.service';

@Injectable()
export class MyResolver implements Resolve<any> {
    constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

    resolve (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> {
        return Observable.from(this.myService.getData());
    }
}
```

**app.routing.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'my-component',
    component: MyComponent,
    resolve: {
        myData: MyDataResolver
    }
  }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

I get an error that there is no provider for `MyDataResolver`. This is still the case when I add `MyDataResolver` to the `providers` property in **app.component.ts**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
  providers: [
        MyService,
        MyResolver
  ]
})
```

Has the interface for using this changed?

Comment: Can you implement the "myData" child's property as a setter and check for 'undefined' there?

Comment: Is it `MyResolver` or `MyDataResolver`. The code in your question seems inconsistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The router supports a promise or an observable returned from `resolve()`.
See also https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

This should do what you want:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyResolver implements Resolve<any> {
    constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

    resolve (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<any> {
        return this.myService.getData();
    }
}
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard

Comment: Based on the second link, I've added `MyResolver` to `providers` in **app.module.ts**, but `child-component`  is still erroring because it's getting the data as undefined. Seems like it's still being instantiated before parent component has the data. Could this be because the parent component is what's waiting for the resolver, not the child component? But the child component doesn't have a route associated with it, and the parent component is the one fetching the data, so I'm not sure how else to make it wait.

Comment: Hard to tell what exactly your code is doing from this description. The simplest way would be adding an `*ngIf` like `<child-component *ngIf="data" [myData]="myData"></child-component>`

Comment: My mistake. I was still trying to extract it via the REST call in the parent component's constructor, rather than extracting it from the route data. Boneheaded of me, sorry.