# Components : Late data initialization?

Tags: angularjs, initialization, components, angular-ui-grid, multi-select

I'm having problem of initializing "elements" in COMPONENTS with data coming from web-request. F.e. (pseudo code) :

```
 <elem elemOpts="$ctrl.elemOpts" />


 .......
 ctrl = this;

 ctrl.web_data = [];
 ctrl.elemOpts = { data : ctrl.web_data }

 ctrl.$onInit = function() {
    $http({ ... }).then(function(response) {
       ctrl.web_data = response.data;
    })
 }
```

This is not working, because the ELEMENT is initialized before $onInit(), so the web request comes afterwards.
Is there a way to execute COMPONENT-code before elements are rendered ?

Two cases which I have this problem is ui-grid and multiselect, where I have to initialize select-boxes from web-request.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch data from **resolve** in routing and inject it in controller.
[this][1] explains better resolve in angular component.

Or you can use ngOnChanges event

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnChanges-class.html   this angular page contain def of onchanges class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38212664/5429428    this is another thread to resolve data before loading