# Angular 2 render after data loaded / parsed

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have an Angular 2 service that does a basic HTTP call to give me back a JSON Object. Once I have that object I do numerous calculations (in my service) that are needed by multiple components in my App. My problem is the components render before the data is retrieved and parsed.

How do I get my components to not load, until the data is retrieved and parsed?

(I've seen the *ngIf="data" solution, but that seems more like a workaround than a permanent fix?)

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38212664/541432

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few valid ways:

1. initialize fields with defaults i.e. `[]`
2. Use `*ngIf`
3. Use css `visibility:hidden`
4. Use `Resolver` guard to fetch and process data.
5. Use `NgComponentOutlet` and create component dynamically.