# Display async values on Angular2 Modal

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I will preface that I am quite new to Angular2. I am trying to display async data on a modal, modal is rendering prior to variables updating.I would prefer to see my variables displayed.

The variables are **winnername** & **winnerurl**, Subject code is at the bottom of the .ts and .html snippets.

Thank You in advance for any input.

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms"; 
import { findfriendService } from '../findfriend.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css'],
  providers: [ findfriendService ]
})

export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {


@ViewChild('myModal') modal: any; 

constructor(private _findfriendService: findfriendService) { }
 
//Submit form
onSubmit(f){
console.log("from click: ", f);

  //post form data to MongoDB
  this._findfriendService.postFriend(f);

  //get all current friends from Mongo DB 
  this._findfriendService.getFriends()
  .subscribe(allFriends =>{
  
      { CODE REMOVED FOR EASE OF VIEWING }
      
      // Code resulting value being assigned to variable index
     for(var a=0;a<plyrsDiff.length;a++){
       var b = plyrsDiff[a];
       if(plyrsDiff[a]<c){
         c = b; 
         index = b; 
       }
    }
    //CONSOLE LOG DISPLAYS VALUES CORRECTLY
    winnername = allFriends[index].firstName;
    winnerurl = allFriends[index].url;
    this.modal.open(); 

  })
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">

    <!--**** Begin of Form  ***********************************-->
    <!--Form variable #f declared -->
    <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.value)">
        <div class="form-group">
            <!--Enter First Name-->
            <label 
                for="firstName">First Name.
            </label>
            <input 
                ngModel name="firstName" 
                #firstName="ngModel"
                class="form-control"
                required
                minlength="3">
                <!-- Show Error if invalid -->
                <div 
                    *ngIf="firstName.touched && firstName.errors">
                    <div 
                        class="alert alert-danger"
                        *ngIf="firstName.errors.required">
                        First name is required
                    </div>
                </div>
           

            <!-- Loop generates 10 user questions-->
                <div  
                    *ngFor="let question of questions; let in = index"> 
                <h5>
                    {{question.q}}
                </h5>
                <!-- display questions, generate select options, assign variable unique to question for ngModel - name - id-->
                <select 
                    required 
                    [(ngModel)]=numbers[in] 
                    name={{question.id}} 
                    id={{question.id}}>  
                    <option   
                        *ngFor="let choice of choices" 
                        [ngValue]="choice">{{choice.label}}
                    </option> 
                </select>
            </div>

     
            <button  
                [disabled]="!f.form.valid" 
                type="submit" 
                class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Submit
            </button>
        </div>
        
         <modal #myModal>
            <modal-header>
                <h1>ALERT</h1>
            </modal-header>
            <modal-content>
            
                <img  src="{{winnerurl}}" height="160">
            </modal-content>
            <modal-footer>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="myModal.close()">close</button>
            </modal-footer>
        </modal>
    </form>
     
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the issue can you  create a plunker?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are subscribing to `._findfriendService.getFriends()` you can't use the async pipe inside your template because you are getting the data already. You need to check if the `winnerurl` or `winnername` is not null then you can show the modal. Try to put `*ngIf` in your modal like this

```
<modal #myModal *ngIf="winnerurl">
        <modal-header>
            <h1>ALERT</h1>
        </modal-header>
        <modal-content>

            <img  src="{{winnerurl}}" height="160">
        </modal-content>
        <modal-footer>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="myModal.close()">close</button>
        </modal-footer>
    </modal>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response, unfortunately this results in a 404 error  "cannot get / search ".

Comment: Hmmm, that is weird because you just insert a *ngIf in your modal. What happens if you remove *ngIf?

Comment: I render a modal without variable being displayed.

Comment: I tried to find your 'winnername' and it is missing in your template. The *ngIf prevents this kind of error because it will not be displayed.

Comment: I had not added it to be displayed yet, trying to get one to work first. Both same issue thought when I tried it.

Comment: Whats the log message? Does it read the data from the service?

Comment: The service works fine for everything except getting the variable to display, the error is induced with the *ngIf while waiting for the variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142027/discussion-between-brijmcq-and-mjr-river).

Answer (score 0):

Answer is found here in similar question on Stack Overflow.

[Wait for Angular 2 to load/resolve model before rendering view/template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731869/wait-for-angular-2-to-load-resolve-model-before-rendering-view-template)